# Delete rows on csv file in c# when the row does not start with a number

Tags: c#, excel, csv

After upload file this **c-sharp** code does convert an **Excel file** to **CSV** format saving with column separated for **`|`**.

But when on the column **"Annotations"** of the Excel file has been entered *break line*, the output on csv format is wrong, because is adding the new rows for each *line break*, please see image below.

[image]

I need delete this row, because row does not start with a number ( **column N** ) or alternatively in the file Excel ( column **Annotations** ) replace the *break line*.

I have tried this *replace code* without success:

```
csvData += result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString().Replace("\r\n", "\n") + "|";
```

How to do resolve this ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

My code below.

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/public/") + filename);
FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

Excel.IExcelDataReader excelReader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
excelReader.Close();
result.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();
string csvData = "";
int row_no = 0;
int ind = 0;

while (row_no < result.Tables[ind].Rows.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[ind].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        csvData += result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + "|";
    }

    row_no++;
    csvData += "\n";
}

output = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/public/target_" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv");                       
StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false);
csv.Write(csvData);
csv.Close();
csv.Dispose();
```

**#Edit 02**

```
while (row_no < result.Tables[ind].Rows.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[ind].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        string text = result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString();
        csvData += text.Replace("\r\n", " ") + "|";
    }

    row_no++;
    csvData += "\n";
}
```

**#Edit 01**

```
while (row_no < result.Tables[ind].Rows.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[ind].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        csvData += result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + "|";
        string text = result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString();
        csvData += text.Replace("\r\n", " ") + "|";
    }

    row_no++;
    csvData += "\n";
}
```

Comment: Too much code - please remove first line from for loop. Only 1 line with csvData += should be inside loop.

Comment: @smartobelix No way ... the output on CSV file don't change, please see #Edit02 in my first question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to eliminate line breaks from the data you are reading.

For example instead this:

```
csvData += result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + "|";
```

You can use the code:

```
string text = result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString();
csvData += text.Replace("\n", " ") + "|";
```

EDIT:

You have to discover what character is causing a problem - maybe it is not \n or \r only another character.

To find out exact problematic character you may use the following technique:

Find first line and column causing a problem, let suppose it is 3rd line, column 5. Then execute the following code (Temporarily change your function):

```
    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/public/") + filename);
    FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    Excel.IExcelDataReader excelReader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
    DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
    excelReader.Close();
    result.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();
    string csvData = "";
    int row_no = 0;
    int ind = 0;

    // Please notice 3 and 5 is row and column number with problematic string
    string problematicValue = result.Tables[ind].Rows[3][5].ToString();
    foreach (char c in problematicValue)
    {
        Debug.Print("Character: " + c + " Code " + (int)c);
    }

    output = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/public/target_" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv");
    StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false);
    csv.Write(csvData);
    csv.Close();
    csv.Dispose();
```

Then in debugger output window you should see output like here:

```
Character: d Code 100
Character: k Code 107
Character: l Code 108
Character: a Code 97
Character: d Code 100
Character: j Code 106
Character: 
 Code 13 <- here is \r
Character: s Code 115
Character: k Code 107
Character: 
 Code 10 <- here in \n
Character: a Code 97
Character: d Code 100
Character: a Code 97
```

Next step will be to change the code to replace problematic character. Please notice there could be more than 1 scenarios in your data (Sometimes only \n or \r, sometimes combination i.e.)

Comment: Thanks for help, but not working, please see **#Edit 01** in my first question.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq `csvData += result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + "|";` needs to be removed from your existing code only @smartobelix' lines remain in the for loop.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel No way ... the output on CSV file don't change, please see #Edit02 in my first question